# Python only looping through the first 2 lines in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looping through a file with ips in it. Only the first 2 lines are looped through although the program seems to know that there are 6 in total.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open('/path/to/ip/list.txt') as file:
  for idx, ln in enumerate(file):
    print(ln)
```

Here's the output after running it:

```
$ ./script.py
6
172.217.6.110

31.192.120.36
```

Here are the contents of the file:

```
$ cat list.txt
172.217.6.110
31.192.120.36
10.234.43.123
192.168.1.1
172.40.432.65
172.20.35.43
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong. My code seems to be consistent with what I'm seeing others write online. What should I do next? I have a linux system and am forcing use of python3 if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: your code is working in my system
but i run your code with this:
python3 script.py
$ ./script.py is not working

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
with open('/path/to/ip/list.txt','r') as file:
  for ln in file.readlines():
    print(ln)
```

Test on my local machine:

[image: Test on my local machine]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.

```
with open('//path//to//ip//list.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```